# SQL stored procedure parameters - approach

Tags: sql, sql-server, web-services, stored-procedures, architecture

I am developing relatively simple database that will manage users, hardware and software on production plant.

I am no expert in database topics. Fragment of database attached below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0BD7.png

I have decided to always use integer surogate key even if fields like login or privilege are unique.

This database will be used by many types of software that not always have decent ORM, and I have decided to interact with DB by using StoredProcedures

My question is about stored procedures and its parameters. For example usp_AddUserRole can be defined as follows:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[User].[usp_AddUserRole]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1)
EXEC
('CREATE PROCEDURE [User].[usp_AddUserRole] AS SET NOCOUNT ON')
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON [User].[usp_AddUserRole] TO sp_executor
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [User].[usp_AddUserRole]
    @UserID numeric(18,0), 
    @RoleID numeric(18,0) AS
SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON

BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    INSERT INTO [User].[User_Role] (
        [UserID]
        ,[RoleID]
        )
    VALUES (
        @UserID
        ,@RoleID
        )

COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@trancount > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    ;THROW
    RETURN -1
END CATCH
GO
```

but this seems to me as not user friendly. 
I could also do this directly by Login and Role values and resolve IDs inside stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [User].[usp_AddUserRole]
    @Login varchar(30), 
    @Role varchar(50) AS
SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON

BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    DECLARE @UserID numeric = (SELECT UserID FROM [User].[User] WHERE [Login] = @Login)
    DECLARE @RoleID numeric = (SELECT RoleID FROM [User].[Role] WHERE [Name] = @Role)

    INSERT INTO [User].[User_Role] (
        [UserID]
        ,[RoleID]
        )
    VALUES (
        @UserID
        ,@RoleID
        )

COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@trancount > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    ;THROW
    RETURN -1
END CATCH
GO
```

This stored procedures will be called from some web services in the future. 
Do You know what approach should be used and why?

Thanks!

Comment: This is opion based, both approaches will work. It you always have the `Id's` at hand the first one will be a tiny bit faster. I do wonder though if the `RETURN -1` statement will still be called after the `;THROW`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both approaches are acceptable. Even better to have two refactored stored procedures: `usp_AddUserRoleByNames` that read IDs and then calls `usp_AddUserRoleByIDs`.

When resolving IDs by names in the stored procedure:

- transaction isolation should be set to REPEATABLE READ at least to prevent modification/deletion of data which have been read
- check NULL values of IDs
- check that user-role link is not exist yet (SERIALISABLE level required)
- don't mix returning of error codes and throwing of exception approaches

Comment: Can you elaborate on your first point, the transaction isolation, please

Comment: For example, the @UserID read in SELECT may be modified or even deleted by another transaction (process) before INSERT. There are different standard levels of transaction isolation supported by DBMS. See more details and examples in the chapter ["Transaction, isolation and locks"](https://www.amazon.com/dp/2956300806)

Comment: Yes I know, I just think this explanation should be in your answer to

Comment: Thanks for very valuable comment. If someone decides to delete @UserID before insert statement happens there will be FK constraint error thrown in this SP so there is no risk of invalid data. If i understand correctly by isolation level I can for example enforce 'lock' on selected rows until this transaction ends?

Comment: @pawhan11 you are able lock data manually, too i.e. with `HOLDLOCK` hint but it may be less efficient compared with locks set by SQL Server engine according to the current isolation level.